# Are there any instances where a negative time type could give unexpected results?

Tags: kdb

Are there any instances where a negative time type could give unexpected results if used for specific purposes? When time deltas are calculated between negative time values and non-negative time values for example, there do not appear to be any issues.

| time | val |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:31.384 | -0.3170017 |
| 00:06:00.139 | 0.9033492 |
| 00:07:01.099 | -0.7661049 |

Then, for the purpose of a window join later over a 10-min window

```
win:00:10:00;
winForJoin: (neg win;00:00:00) +\:(exec time from data);
```

first[winForJoin] gives -00:09:28.616 -00:03:59.861 -00:02:58.901

winForJoin[1]-winForJoin[0] gives 10 minutes as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking how would a window join behave if the opening interval was a negative time? (due to the interval subtraction taking the values into negative territory, relative to 00:00).

The simple answer is that it won't behave any differently than if the times were numbers, but in practice you may see results you don't expect depending on how your table is set up and what you're trying to achieve.

Taking the example in the official wiki as a starting point: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/wj/

```
q)t:([]sym:3#`ibm;time:10:01:01 10:01:04 10:01:08;price:100 101 105)
q)a:101 103 103 104 104 107 108 107 108
q)b:98 99 102 103 103 104 106 106 107
q)q:([]sym:`ibm; time:10:01:01+til 9; ask:a; bid:b)
q)f:`sym`time
q)w:-2 1+\:t.time

/add volume too so it's easier to follow:
q)s:908 360 522 257 858 585 90 683 90;
q)update size:s from `q

/add an alternative range which has negative starting time
q)w2:(-11:00;1)+\:t.time
```

The window join takes all rows in `q` whose times are between the pairs of time ranges:

```
q)q[`time]within/:flip w
110000000b
011110000b
000001111b
```

Under the covers it's asking: are these positive numbers (the quote times) in between those two positive numbers (the window range). There's no reason it can't also ask: are these positive numbers in between this negative number and this positive number

```
q)q[`time]within/:flip w2
110000000b
111110000b
111111111b
```

You'll notice that *all* of them are greater than the negative time - meaning that it will include *all* rows from the beginning of the `q` table, up until the end time of that pair. This can be considered expected behaviour - if your start time is negative you must mean "from the beginning of time" - aka, all rows from the beginning of the table.

Comparing sum of size shows how the results differ:

```
q)wj[w;f;t;(q;(sum;`size))]
sym time     price size
-----------------------
ibm 10:01:01 100   1268
ibm 10:01:04 101   1997
ibm 10:01:08 105   1448
q)wj[w2;f;t;(q;(sum;`size))]
sym time     price size
-----------------------
ibm 10:01:01 100   1268
ibm 10:01:04 101   2905
ibm 10:01:08 105   4353
```

Finally - where it might get complicated.....it depends on what "negative" time means in your table. If you're at 00:00 (midnight) and you subtract 10 minutes, are you trying to access data from 23:50 the day before? Or does 00:00 represent the starting time (row zero) of your table? If you're trying to access 23:50 from the day before then you will have problems because 23:50 is *NOT* in between your negative start time and your positive end time, e.g:

```
q)23:50 within(-00:58:59;10:01:02)
0b
```

Again this all depends on how your data looks and what you're trying to do